# Find length of a string that includes its own length?

Tags: python, string, recursion, string-length

I want to get the length of a string including a part of the string that represents its own length without padding or using structs or anything like that that forces fixed lengths.

So for example I want to be able to take this string as input:

```
"A string|"
```

And return this:

```
"A string|11"
```

Comment: How is [tag:recursion] relevant here? Do you actually have any code? Where precisely is your problem?

Comment: The problem 'feels' recursive as the string's overall length changes as the program appends it's length to the string. I don't have any code because I can't wrap my head around any algorithm at all - iterative or otherwise.

Comment: What's your longest string?  A general formula is possible, but if your strings are of length < 997, then there are only 3 cases, and it's easier to just write those out.

Comment: Sadly there's no cap on string lengths in my implementation. I'm using it for socket communications where the length of the message (including the part of the header that describes the length) needs to be communicated inside the message. I ended up using structs but that imposes a limit on the amount of data I can send based on the max size of the struct while using delimited values would allow for messages of infinite size.

Comment: Would you tolerate a crude solution in Java?

Comment: Even with no cap, you only need to add `log(len(s))` characters to the string, which means there are only a few edge cases where `len(new_s) = len(s + log(len(s))` is not true.

Comment: See why answer. since it uses len(string) at the point of execution, it gets reset every time it is created..

Comment: @Bathsheba any language is awesome, I more want to get a grasp of how you'd approach the problem than just drop in code

Comment: I can't resist. Java solution up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the basis of the OP tolerating such an approach (and to provide an implementation technique for the eventual python answer), here's a solution in Java.

```java
 final String s = "A String|";
 int n = s.length(); // `length()` returns the length of the string.
 String t; // the result
 do {
      t = s + n; // append the stringified n to the original string
      if (n == t.length()){
          return t; // string length no longer changing; we're good.
      }                       
      n = t.length(); // n must hold the total length
 } while (true); // round again
```

The problem of, course, is that in appending `n`, the string length changes. But luckily, the length only ever *increases* or stays the same. So it will converge very quickly: due to the logarithmic nature of the length of `n`. In this particular case, the attempted values of `n` are 9, 10, and 11. And that's a pernicious case.

Comment: I didn't read this closely before posting essentially the same thing in Python.

Comment: I don't understand why you deleted that answer. Was it wrong?

Comment: I eventually got it right, but I don't think it's a good idea to have multiple answers all showing the same algorithm, just in different languages. The *ideal* answer would just show the algorithm in pseudocode ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is :

```
def addlength(string):
    n1=len(string)
    n2=len(str(n1))+n1
    n2 += len(str(n2))-len(str(n1)) # a carry can arise
    return string+str(n2)
```

Since a possible carry will increase the length by at most one unit.

Examples :

```
In [2]: addlength('a'*8)
Out[2]: 'aaaaaaaa9'

In [3]: addlength('a'*9)
Out[3]: 'aaaaaaaaa11'

In [4]: addlength('a'*99)
Out[4]: 'aaaaa...aaa102'

In [5]: addlength('a'*999)
Out[5]: 'aaaa...aaa1003'
```

Comment: As done here, it's better to calculate the length of the string first before doing the append, especially for long strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple python port of Bathsheba's answer :

```
def str_len(s):
    n = len(s)
    t = ''
    while True:
        t = s + str(n)
        if n == len(t):
            return t
        n = len(t)
```

This is a much more clever and simple way than anything I was thinking of trying!

Suppose you had `s = 'abcdefgh|`, On the first pass through, `t = 'abcdefgh|9`
Since `n != len(t)` ( which is now 10 ) it goes through again : `t = 'abcdefgh|' + str(n)` and `str(n)='10'` so you have `abcdefgh|10` which is still not quite right! Now `n=len(t)` which is finally `n=11` you get it right then. Pretty clever solution!

Comment: Plus one; it comes out rather nicely in Python.

Answer (score 1):

It is a tricky one, but I *think* I've figured it out.

Done in a hurry in Python 2.7, please fully test - this should handle strings up to 998 characters:

```
import sys

orig = sys.argv[1]

origLen = len(orig)

if (origLen >= 98):
    extra = str(origLen + 3)
elif (origLen >= 8):
    extra = str(origLen + 2)
else:
    extra = str(origLen + 1)

final = orig + extra

print final
```

**Results of very brief testing**

C:\Users\PH\Desktop>python test.py "tiny|"

**tiny|6**

C:\Users\PH\Desktop>python test.py "myString|"

**myString|11**

C:\Users\PH\Desktop>python test.py "myStringWith98Characters.........................................................................|"

**myStringWith98Characters.........................................................................|101**

Answer (score 1):

Just find the length of the string. Then iterate through each value of **the number of digits** the length of the resulting string can possibly have. While iterating, check if the sum of the number of digits to be appended and the **initial** string length is equal to the length of the **resulting** string.

```
def get_length(s):
    s = s + "|"
    result = ""
    len_s = len(s)
    i = 1
    while True:
        candidate = len_s + i
        if len(str(candidate)) == i:
            result = s + str(len_s + i)
            break
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a direct equation for this (so it's not necessary to construct the string).  If `s` is the string, then the length of the string including the length of the appended length will be:

```
L1 = len(s) + 1 + int(log10(len(s) + 1 + int(log10(len(s)))))
```

The idea here is that a direct calculation is only problematic when the appended length will push the length past a power of ten; that is, at `9`, `98`, `99`, `997`, `998`, `999`, `9996`, etc.  To work this through, `1 + int(log10(len(s)))` is the number of digits in the length of `s`.  If we add that to `len(s)`, then `9->10`, `98->100`, `99->101`, etc, but still `8->9`, `97->99`, etc, so we can push past the power of ten exactly as needed.  That is, adding this produces a number with the correct number of digits after the addition.  Then do the log again to find the length of that number and that's the answer.

To test this:

```
from math import log10

def find_length(s):
    L1 = len(s) + 1 + int(log10(len(s) + 1 + int(log10(len(s)))))
    return L1

# test, just looking at lengths around 10**n
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(30):
        L = abs(10**i - j + 10) + 1
        s = "a"*L
        x0 = find_length(s)
        new0 = s+`x0`
        if len(new0)!=x0:
            print "error", len(s), x0, log10(len(s)), log10(x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives the result.

I used a few `var`, but at the end it shows the output you want:

```
def len_s(s):
    s = s + '|'
    b = len(s)
    z = s + str(b)
    length = len(z)
    new_s = s + str(length)
    new_len = len(new_s)
    return s + str(new_len)

s = "A string"
print len_s(s)
```